# How to access variable from the while loop in the function to the outside the function in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-iot-hub, .net-4.8

I am sending telemetry(data) from simulator device to Azure IoT Hub and receiving that telemetry into this code.

```
 namespace CentralSystem
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static readonly string connectionString = "IoT Hub Connection string here";
    static readonly string iotHubD2cEndpoint = "messages/events";
    static EventHubClient eventHubClient;

    public static Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken ct)   
    {
        var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);
        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;

            EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
            if (eventData == null) continue;

            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
            values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);  
            foreach (var kv in values)                                                 
            {                                                                          
                Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + " : " + kv.Value);                          
            }                                                                          
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

This above code run perfectly but I need to access "**data**" variable outside the function means access it globally. Because I need to put all values in "**data**" variable to dictionary. so that I have declared dictionary as globally.

Please tell me that how to figure out this thing?

Comment: Just declare `data` at same scope as your `Dictionary`

Comment: you don't have to access data outside the function to write it into your dictionary as the dictionary is available inside the loop.

Comment: If this is part of some kind of server, what persistence model does the server have? The typical solution would be to use a database to store data between requests. That way your data is consistent even if the server is restarted.

Comment: You are now rewriting those "values" every time you get new data. Do you maybe want to deserialize "data" into a local dictionary that you then add to (or update) in the global "values"?

Comment: I want both keys and values from dictionary not only values. sorry to say at this line public static Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>(); values are just a object of dictionary not the values we want to access from the dictionary. I want to access dictionary as globally means outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly.
Isn't it stored in your "values" dictionary?

If you need only values:
Create List of strings above the function (like your values):

```
List<string> listOfValues = new List<string>()
```

and do this like a dictionary but only for Values:

```
listOfValues.Add(Value)
```

After the function, do what you want with it

Comment: I want both keys and values from dictionary not only values. sorry to say at this line                            public static Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();         values are just a object of dictionary not the values we want to access from the dictionary. I want to access dictionary as globally means outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have provided you are already storing all values of the "data" variable in the dictionary "values" which is globally declared. You can directly use "values" to proceed further and access the data inside it.

Comment: while using "Values" variable outside the function it throws an error like, "The name 'DeserializeObject<Dictionary <string, string>>' does not exist in the current context". so what I do? otherwise please can you provide the code so that I can implement it.